# Render data from a database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, async-await, cross-platform

Say I want to fetch someone's name from a firebase database to render in JSX for a React Native project. I want to render something as follows

```
return(
 <View>
   <Text>{name} retrieved data!</Text>
 </View>)
```

Where name is some data stored in the realtime database. To get the "name" variable, I would need to make an async call to the database. However, I only want to render the JSX if I have the correct value for name. How can I go about doing this? I realize this is a simple example, but that was the point, as I spent hours trying to figure out the answer to a more complex version of this. When trying to do this, I would get an error since name was undefined at the time of rendering due to the async call to the database.

Comment: `name` is a state?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the data yet, you can render something else while you're still loading.

For example something like:

```
if (!name) {
  return null
}

return (
  <View>
    <Text>{name} retrieved data!</Text>
  </View>
)
```

Some kind of loading indicator would probably be better than the null.